# Jira start up failed with custom plugin using rest api (jersey)

Tags: jersey, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

We are working on a jira custom plugin which uses rest api.

After installing the custom plugin, when we restart jira, it fails.

We are facing following exception in the logs:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'activator' defined in URL [bundle://109.0:0/META-INF/spring/atlassian-plugins-components.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.jersey.spi.HeaderDelegateProvider: The class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.LocaleProvider implementing provider interface com.sun.jersey.spi.HeaderDelegateProvider could not be instantiated: Cannot cast com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.LocaleProvider to com.sun.jersey.spi.HeaderDelegateProvider
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$1600(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:69)
at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$4.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:355)
at org.springframework.osgi.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)
at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.completeRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:320)
at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor$CompleteRefreshTask.run(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:132)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.jersey.spi.HeaderDelegateProvider: The class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.LocaleProvider implementing provider interface com.sun.jersey.spi.HeaderDelegateProvider could not be instantiated: Cannot cast com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.LocaleProvider to com.sun.jersey.spi.HeaderDelegateProvider
at com.sun.jersey.core.osgi.Activator$OsgiServiceFinder$1.next(Activator.java:80)
at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.AbstractRuntimeDelegate.<init>(AbstractRuntimeDelegate.java:76)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.provider.RuntimeDelegateImpl.<init>(RuntimeDelegateImpl.java:54)
at com.sun.jersey.server.osgi.Activator.start(Activator.java:63)
at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.Activator.afterPropertiesSet(Activator.java:22)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.LocaleProvider to com.sun.jersey.spi.HeaderDelegateProvider
at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3084)
at com.sun.jersey.core.osgi.Activator$OsgiServiceFinder$1.next(Activator.java:78)
... 25 more
```

Can you please suggest solution for the above exception?

**atlassian-plugin.xml** file for this plugin:

```
<atlassian-plugin key="${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}" name="${project.name}" plugins-version="2">
    <plugin-info>
        <description>${project.description}</description>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <vendor name="${project.organization.name}" url="${project.organization.url}" />
        <param name="plugin-icon">images/pluginIcon.png</param>
        <param name="plugin-logo">images/pluginLogo.png</param>
    </plugin-info>

  <web-resource key="QC-Jira-Linkage" name="QC-Jira-Linkage Web Resources">
        <dependency>com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs</dependency>
    <!--     <resource type="download" name="qc-jira-linkage.css" location="css/qc-jira-linkage.css"/> -->
        <resource type="download" name="qc-jira-linkage.js" location="js/qc-jira-linkage.js"/>
        <resource type="download" name="images/" location="images/"/>
        <context>QC-Jira-Linkage</context>
        <context>atl.general</context>
       <context>atl.admin</context>


  </web-resource> 
     <!-- add our i18n resource -->
    <resource type="i18n" name="qc-jira-linkage" location="qc-jira-linkage"/>

     <web-item key="add-qc-link" section="create-issue-link-types" weight="20">
        <label key="com.example.externallinkage.type" />
        <link linkId="add-qc-link">
            /secure/LinkQC!default.jspa?id=${issueId}
        </link> 
    </web-item>
    <component key="link-service" class="com.example.externallinkage.LinkService"/>

    <component-import key="activityService" interface="com.atlassian.streams.thirdparty.api.ActivityService"/>
    <component-import key="sal-request-factory" interface="com.atlassian.sal.api.net.RequestFactory"/>

    <webwork1 key="issue-link-qc" name="Link Issues With QC" class="java.lang.Object">
        <actions>
            <action name="com.example.externallinkage.LinkQC" alias="LinkQC">
                <view name="error">/templates/qc-jira-linkage-view.vm</view>
                <view name="input">/templates/qc-jira-linkage-view.vm</view>
            </action>
        </actions>
    </webwork1>



    <component-import key="remote-issue-link-service" interface="com.atlassian.jira.bc.issue.link.RemoteIssueLinkService"/>

    <issue-link-renderer key="qc-jira-linkagekey" application-type="com.example.externallinkage" class="com.example.externallinkage.JiraQCLinkRenderer">
         <resource name="initial-view" type="velocity" location="templates/renderer/loadingissuelink.vm"/>
        <resource name="final-view" type="velocity" location="templates/renderer/qclink.vm"/>
    </issue-link-renderer>

    <component-import key="userManager" interface="com.atlassian.sal.api.user.UserManager" />
    <component-import key="loginUriProvider" interface="com.atlassian.sal.api.auth.LoginUriProvider" />
    <component-import key="renderer" interface="com.atlassian.templaterenderer.velocity.one.six.VelocityTemplateRenderer" />
    <component-import key="applicationProperties" interface="com.atlassian.sal.api.ApplicationProperties" />
    <component-import key="pluginSettingsFactory" interface="com.atlassian.sal.api.pluginsettings.PluginSettingsFactory" />
    <component-import key="transactionTemplate" interface="com.atlassian.sal.api.transaction.TransactionTemplate" />
    <template-context-item key="applicationPropertiesContextItem" component-ref="applicationProperties"
                        context-key="applicationProperties" name="Application Properties Context Item"/> 

    <servlet key="link-servlet" class="com.example.externallinkage.LinkServlet">
      <url-pattern>/asurion/TestInstanceDetails</url-pattern>

    </servlet>


    <webwork1 key="DeleteLink" name="DeleteLink" class="java.lang.Object">
              <actions>
                     <action name="com.example.externallinkage.RemoteDeleteLink" alias="DeleteRemoteIssueLink" roles-required="use">
                        <view name="input">/secure/views/issue/deletelink.jsp</view>
                        <view name="error">/secure/views/issue/deletelink.jsp</view>
                    </action>
              </actions>
       </webwork1>   

</atlassian-plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't edit the question, so adding more details here.

**atlassian-plugin.xml** file for this plugin, as requested in a comment now gone :(

```
<atlassian-plugin key="${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}" name="${project.name}" plugins-version="2">
    <plugin-info>
        <description>${project.description}</description>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <vendor name="${project.organization.name}" url="${project.organization.url}" />
        <param name="plugin-icon">images/pluginIcon.png</param>
        <param name="plugin-logo">images/pluginLogo.png</param>
    </plugin-info>

  <web-resource key="QC-Jira-Linkage" name="QC-Jira-Linkage Web Resources">
        <dependency>com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs</dependency>
    <!--     <resource type="download" name="qc-jira-linkage.css" location="css/qc-jira-linkage.css"/> -->
        <resource type="download" name="qc-jira-linkage.js" location="js/qc-jira-linkage.js"/>
        <resource type="download" name="images/" location="images/"/>
        <context>QC-Jira-Linkage</context>
        <context>atl.general</context>
       <context>atl.admin</context>


  </web-resource> 
     <!-- add our i18n resource -->
    <resource type="i18n" name="qc-jira-linkage" location="qc-jira-linkage"/>

     <web-item key="add-qc-link" section="create-issue-link-types" weight="20">
        <label key="com.example.externallinkage.type" />
        <link linkId="add-qc-link">
            /secure/LinkQC!default.jspa?id=${issueId}
        </link> 
    </web-item>
    <component key="link-service" class="com.example.externallinkage.LinkService"/>

    <component-import key="activityService" interface="com.atlassian.streams.thirdparty.api.ActivityService"/>
    <component-import key="sal-request-factory" interface="com.atlassian.sal.api.net.RequestFactory"/>

    <webwork1 key="issue-link-qc" name="Link Issues With QC" class="java.lang.Object">
        <actions>
            <action name="com.example.externallinkage.LinkQC" alias="LinkQC">
                <view name="error">/templates/qc-jira-linkage-view.vm</view>
                <view name="input">/templates/qc-jira-linkage-view.vm</view>
            </action>
        </actions>
    </webwork1>



    <component-import key="remote-issue-link-service" interface="com.atlassian.jira.bc.issue.link.RemoteIssueLinkService"/>

    <issue-link-renderer key="qc-jira-linkagekey" application-type="com.example.externallinkage" class="com.example.externallinkage.JiraQCLinkRenderer">
         <resource name="initial-view" type="velocity" location="templates/renderer/loadingissuelink.vm"/>
        <resource name="final-view" type="velocity" location="templates/renderer/qclink.vm"/>
    </issue-link-renderer>

    <component-import key="userManager" interface="com.atlassian.sal.api.user.UserManager" />
    <component-import key="loginUriProvider" interface="com.atlassian.sal.api.auth.LoginUriProvider" />
    <component-import key="renderer" interface="com.atlassian.templaterenderer.velocity.one.six.VelocityTemplateRenderer" />
    <component-import key="applicationProperties" interface="com.atlassian.sal.api.ApplicationProperties" />
    <component-import key="pluginSettingsFactory" interface="com.atlassian.sal.api.pluginsettings.PluginSettingsFactory" />
    <component-import key="transactionTemplate" interface="com.atlassian.sal.api.transaction.TransactionTemplate" />
    <template-context-item key="applicationPropertiesContextItem" component-ref="applicationProperties"
                        context-key="applicationProperties" name="Application Properties Context Item"/> 

    <servlet key="link-servlet" class="com.example.externallinkage.LinkServlet">
      <url-pattern>/asurion/TestInstanceDetails</url-pattern>

    </servlet>


    <webwork1 key="DeleteLink" name="DeleteLink" class="java.lang.Object">
              <actions>
                     <action name="com.example.externallinkage.RemoteDeleteLink" alias="DeleteRemoteIssueLink" roles-required="use">
                        <view name="input">/secure/views/issue/deletelink.jsp</view>
                        <view name="error">/secure/views/issue/deletelink.jsp</view>
                    </action>
              </actions>
       </webwork1>   

</atlassian-plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it wasn't connected with atlassian-plugin.xml at all. Could you attach pom.xml as well? If not whole, dependencies section only.

If you used `atlas-create-jira-plugin`, and/or `atlas-create-jira-plugin-module` to generate pom, it might not be usable at all.
There's diff of my changes, that solved problem with stacktrace you encountered as well:

```
-        <dependency>
-            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins.rest</groupId>
-            <artifactId>atlassian-rest-common</artifactId>
-            <version>2.9.2</version>
-        </dependency>
+        <dependency>
+            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
+            <artifactId>jira-rest-plugin</artifactId>
+            <version>${jira.version}</version>
+            <scope>provided</scope>
+        </dependency>
```

Hope it helps.